# Netbeans Não reconhece arquivo .jasper

Tags: jsf-2.2, netbeans, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

Estou com problemas para chamar relatório aplicação JSF. Não busca dados no NetBeans 8.1 não reconhece arquivo gerado Jaspersoft. Não encontro *plugin* para esta versão.

RelatorioPedidosEmitidos.xhtml

```
<ui:define name="titulo">Relatório de pedidos emitidos</ui:define>

<ui:define name="corpo">
    <h:form id="frm">
        <h1>Relatório de pedidos emitidos</h1>

        <p:messages autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />

        <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
            <p:toolbarGroup>
                <p:commandButton value="Emitir" action="#{relatorioPedidosEmitidosBean.emitir}"
                    ajax="true" />
            </p:toolbarGroup>
        </p:toolbar>

        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="painel" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px"
                columnClasses="rotulo, campo">
            <p:outputLabel value="Data de criação" />
            <h:panelGroup>
                <p:calendar value="#{relatorioPedidosEmitidosBean.dataInicio}" label="Data inicial" 
                    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" size="8" />
                <p:spacer width="8" />
                <h:outputText value="a" />
                <p:spacer width="8" />
                <p:calendar value="#{relatorioPedidosEmitidosBean.dataFim}" label="Data final" 
                    pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" size="8" />
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
```

RelatorioPedidosEmitidosBean.java

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class RelatorioPedidosEmitidosBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

private Date dataInicio;
private Date dataFim;

@Inject
private FacesContext facesContext;

@Inject
private HttpServletResponse response;

@Inject
private EntityManager manager;

public void emitir() {
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
    parametros.put("data_inicio", this.dataInicio);
    parametros.put("data_fim", this.dataFim);

    ExecutorRelatorio executor = new ExecutorRelatorio("/relatorios/relatorios_pedidos_vendas.jasper",
            this.response, parametros, "Pedidos emitidos.pdf");

    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
    session.doWork(executor);

    if (executor.isRelatorioGerado()) {
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    } else {
        FacesUtil.addErrorMessage("A execução do relatório não retornou dados.");
    }
}

@NotNull
public Date getDataInicio() {
    return dataInicio;
}

public void setDataInicio(Date dataInicio) {
    this.dataInicio = dataInicio;
}

@NotNull
public Date getDataFim() {
    return dataFim;
}

public void setDataFim(Date dataFim) {
    this.dataFim = dataFim;
}
```

}

ExecutorRelatorio.java

```
public class ExecutorRelatorio implements Work {

private String caminhoRelatorio;
private HttpServletResponse response;
private Map<String, Object> parametros;
private String nomeArquivoSaida;

private boolean relatorioGerado;

public ExecutorRelatorio(String caminhoRelatorio,
        HttpServletResponse response, Map<String, Object> parametros,
        String nomeArquivoSaida) {
    this.caminhoRelatorio = caminhoRelatorio;
    this.response = response;
    this.parametros = parametros;
    this.nomeArquivoSaida = nomeArquivoSaida;

    this.parametros.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("pt", "BR"));
}

@Override
public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    try {
        InputStream relatorioStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.caminhoRelatorio);

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorioStream, this.parametros, connection);
        this.relatorioGerado = print.getPages().size() > 0;

        if (this.relatorioGerado) {
            Exporter<ExporterInput, PdfReportConfiguration, PdfExporterConfiguration, 
                OutputStreamExporterOutput> exportador = new JRPdfExporter();
            exportador.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
            exportador.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(response.getOutputStream()));

                            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, response.getOutputStream());

            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" 
                    + this.nomeArquivoSaida  + "\"");

            exportador.exportReport();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SQLException("Erro ao executar relatório " + this.caminhoRelatorio, e);
    }
}

public boolean isRelatorioGerado() {
    return relatorioGerado;
}
```

log quando tento emitir relatorio;

MonitorFilter::WARNING: the monitor filter must be the first filter in the       chain.
MonitorFilter::WARNING: the monitor filter must be the first filter in the chain.
Hibernate: select usuario0_.id as id1_7_, usuario0_.email as email2_7_, usuario0_.nome as nome3_7_, usuario0_.senha as senha4_7_ from usuario usuario0_ where lower(usuario0_.email)=?
Hibernate: select grupos0_.usuario_id as usuario_1_8_0_, grupos0_.grupo_id as grupo_id2_8_0_, grupo1_.id as id1_3_1_, grupo1_.descricao as descrica2_3_1_, grupo1_.nome as nome3_3_1_ from usuario_grupo grupos0_ inner join grupo grupo1_ on grupos0_.grupo_id=grupo1_.id where grupos0_.usuario_id=?
MonitorFilter::WARNING: the monitor filter must be the first filter in the chain.
Hibernate: select date(data_criacao) as data, sum(this_.valor_total) as y1_ from pedido this_ where this_.data_criacao>=? group by date(data_criacao)
Hibernate: select date(data_criacao) as data, sum(this_.valor_total) as y1_ from pedido this_ where this_.data_criacao>=? and this_.vendedor_id=? group by date(data_criacao)
MonitorFilter::WARNING: the monitor filter must be the first filter in the chain.
MonitorFilter::WARNING: the monitor filter must be the first filter in the chain.

Imagem package
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Seja mais específico... Sua questão está muito confusa.

Comment: gerei um relatório no jaspersoft copiei o mesmo para pasta da aplicação no netbeans, só que acusa arquivo não reconhecido, pois não tenho plugin ireport instalado, mas este plugin só tem versão para netbeans 7.4. teria algum problema instalar está versão no meu netbeans 8.1. ou existe outra forma de resolver este detalhe?

Comment: baixei instalei jasper netbeans  está reconhecendo mas no meu ao tentar emitir relatórios passa exceção não encontra nenhum dado, sendo que existe dados para serem carregados,

Comment: Coloque trechos dos códigos. imagens, etc, para que possamos melhor lhe ajudar!

Comment: está ai desde já agradeço!

Comment: Poderia colocar uma imagem de seu package explorer maximizado?

Comment: coloquei Nayron,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para gerar o relatório com o JasperReport você vai precisar das seguintes bibliotecas:

- commons-beanutils
- commons-collections
- commons-digester
- commons-logging
- groovy-all
- iText poi
- jasperreports

Verifique se tem todas elas adicionada e configurada ao seu projeto, utilize o Ireport ou o JasperStudio para desenvolver o design do relatório, observando que o primeiro só é compatível com Java 7. De tal forma que não haverá nenhuma dependência ao Netbeans, tudo se dará de forma independente.

Espero ter ajudado!